# What does it mean to be 'bounded'

Tags: proof-of-stake

I see this terminology everywhere in ethereum Wikis. What does it mean to be 'bounded'? Its a noob question I know.

Comment: It might help if you linked to one of these references (or at least quoted it here).

Comment: For example, https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Proof-of-Stake-FAQ ... just search "bound" in that wiki.

Comment: Or on Vitalik article's : https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/01/28/p-epsilon-attack/  search for "unbounded" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 'bound' is another way of saying 'limit'. 'Limited' and 'bounded' are pretty much the same. The capability of a system is limited to within the bounds specified, so we could say it is bounded.

Comment: This answer is correct. I want to add that this term and its usage is not specific to Ethereum.